# Best way to design organization-specific models in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, relational-database

This is a database model design question. Let's say I'm designing an app like Slack. Slack has multiple Organizations, and within each Organization there are objects that only should be accessed by that Organization (eg. its chat records, files, etc.). What is the best way to set up these per-Organization objects in Django?

A simple solution is to attach a ForeignKey to every one of these objects. Like so:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    # ...

class File(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        'Organization',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # ...

class ChatThread(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        'Organization',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # ...
```

But if we do it like this, we need to put an index on `organization`, and since there are many such per-Organization objects, it seems a little wasteful.

Is there a cleaner way to design this?

Comment: why do you think it's wasteful? At some level you want to have `File`s associated with some `Organization` and relating them with ForeignKey/ManyToMany is the best way I can think of.

Answer (score 6):

I think your method is about as good as it would need to be. In terms of indexing the organization column, you can use `db_index=False` to disable the creation of an index.

If you want to abstract the organization field and have some methods available on all organization objects, you could use an abstract model like so:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    # ...

class OrganizationModel(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        'Organization',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_index=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class File(OrganizationModel):
    # ...

class ChatThread(OrganizationModel):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Your method is clean, if each `Organization` can share the same `File` then you should use `models.ManytoManyField`, but I doubt Slack works like this.

On top of that, using Slack you can access files from anywhere but each file you share can't always be published just on every thread.

The model structure you offer seems like the best for what you're trying to achieve, if you happen to have people in each organization using your app then you might want to design a new model for each person.

Here's what I'd go with :

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    # ...

#each person is part of an organization
class Person(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...

#each file is part of an organization
class File(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
# ...

#each thread is part an Organization
#each thread can have many users, each user can join many thread.
#each thread can have many files, each file can be shared across one or many thread
class ChatThread(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Person, ...)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File, ...)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the true question is :

Did your File Models always need Organisation ?
Same question for ChatThread Models ?

If not then, you shouldn't use ForeignKey, but ManyToManyField.
And then you avoid Models dependencies.

Else, you models are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that, but if you are designing an app like Slack i think you need design it using Tenants, for example: customer.domain.com, it's better to organize the information.

In your base organization you can do it like this example:

```
# The Organization Model
class Organization(models.Model):
  # ...

#each person is part of an organization
class Person(models.Model):
  organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  # ...

#each file is part of an organization
class File(models.Model):
  organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  # ...

#each thread is part an Organization
#each thread can have many users, each user can join many thread.
#each thread can have many files, each file can be shared across one or many thread
class ChatThread(models.Model):
  organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  people = models.ManyToManyField(Person, ...)
  files = models.ManyToManyField(File, ...)
  # ...
```